# Append 2 dimensional arrays to one single array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a loop over 2-dimensional np.arrays() and I need to add these arrays to one single array.

in plain Python I would do this

```
In [37]: a1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]

In [38]: b1 = [[5,6],[7,8]]

In [39]: l1 = []

In [40]: l1.append(a1)

In [41]: l1.append(b1)

In [42]: l1
Out[42]: [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

How do I get the same result with numpy for l1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to produce that output from the arrays:

```
>>> np.dstack((a1,b1)).transpose(2,0,1)

array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],
```

`np.dstack` produces a 3D array, but the axes need to read in a different order. We want the order of  the axes `(0, 1, 2)` changed to `(2, 0, 1)`, hence the need to transpose and swap the axes.

---

Below is potentially useful - but not immediately relevant - information about concatenating arrays. (Typed before my misinterpretation of the question was pointed out.)

One way to join arrays is to use `np.concatenate`:

```
>>> np.concatenate((a1, b1))
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

This stacks one below the other. You can also concatenate the arrays side-by-side with `np.concatenate((a1, b1), axis=1)`. (More than two arrays can be passed into the function.)

There are other functions to do this; the two operations above can be done with `np.vstack((a1,b1))` and `np.hstack((a1,b1))` respectively.

If you want to join in the arrays in a 3D array, you can use `np.dstack((a1,b1))`:

```
array([[[1, 5],
        [2, 6]],

       [[3, 7],
        [4, 8]]])
```

Keep in mind that Numpy arrays, unlike Python lists, cannot grow in memory dynamically. These operations cause the arrays to be copied and a new block of memory to be filled with the bigger array. This can be inefficient if the arrays are large.

Comment: This is really good information for a newcomer to `numpy`. Notice however that none of these solutions provides the required output

Comment: @gg349 You're quite right - I misread the question. I'll delete this answer and try and fix when I have the chance. Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer should stay and it is valuable info for the OP

Comment: @gg349 The answer using `dstack` provides the required output, even if the formatting is different.

Comment: I am not sure. with `dstack` you start with `1,5`. It should be `1,2`

Comment: Notice moreover that `swapaxes` will return a view on the array.

Comment: Yes that is true - if the data needs to be laid out in memory a particular way it will be be necessary to `copy('C')` the array. For this reason, as well the speed difference (`dstack` is slower), I prefer both yours and ubutnu's methods over the one I suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
l1 = np.array([a1,b1])
```

Notice also that in `numpy` you don't append to arrays. You allocate them first, and then you fill them:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b1 = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
#allocate exact size of the final array
l1 = empty(((2,)+a1.shape),dtype=a1.dtype)
l1[0]=a1
l1[1]=b1
```

or you use one of the many helper functions (`dstack`,`hstack`,`concatenate` described by the others)

EDIT: I find both solutions above very readable and close to python lists syntax, but this is rather subjective. Timing how fast this is, you find that both solutions are marginally faster to the fastest solution proposed by @unutbu, based on concatenate. Notice moreover that this does not create a view.

Comment: Indeed, this is *much* faster than my suggestion (for large arrays).

Answer (score 3):

```
a1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b1 = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
l1 = np.r_['0,3', a1, b1]
```

yields

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
```

The special directive `'0,3'` tells [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate along `axis=0`, and produce a result with at least 3 dimensions.

---

Or, alternatively, using `concatenate` and `reshape` is more readable and faster:

```
l1 = np.concatenate([a1, b1]).reshape((2,)+a1.shape))
```

---

```
In [111]: a2 = np.tile(a1, (10000,1))

In [112]: b2 = np.tile(b1, (10000,1))

In [113]: %timeit np.r_['0,3', a2, b2].shape
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.4 µs per loop

In [114]: %timeit np.concatenate([a2, b2]).reshape((2,)+a2.shape)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: reshaping in the general case with `a1,b1` you would have to write `np.concatenate([a1, b1]).reshape((2,a1.shape[0],-1))`. I don't find it much more readable.

Comment: @gg349: Indeed, readability is subjective. `concatenate/reshape` is only more readable *to me* because I use them more often than `r_` with special directives like `'0,3'` (which I have to look up to remember how to use.)